# How to get Find And Replace to work in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, find, visual-studio-2022, findall, asp.net-core-6.0

When I click on 'Find All' in the 'Find and Replace' (CTRL + SHIFT + F), it is not returning me correct results.

I noted that in the Find output  window, it says 'Total Files searched: 2'. So it is just searching two files for all the texts. When I searched for simple text like '{' or 'select', it returns me result from wwwroot\css file and still returns only two files.

In the find window, I've selected file type as : *.cs;*.vb;*.resx;*.xsd;*.wsdl;*.htm;*.html;*.aspx;*.ascx;*.asmx;*.svc;*.asax;*.config;*.asp;*.asa;*.cshtml;*.vbhtml;*.razor;*.css;*.xml and also selected Look in: 'Entire solution'

[image]

I've tried checking unchecking all options on page like Match Case, Match Whole Word, User Regular Expression, Include miscellaneous files etc. Nothing seem to be helping expand the search on other files. It still says Total Files Searched: 2.

Attached screenshot is an example that Title is available on the page I've opened in the background but search doesn't return that in result. The search is getting limited to two pages(two css files), it is not searching the entire solution.

Any pointers on how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the find and replace dialog window with your input supplied as well as the results window/tab?

Comment: @TimothyG. Just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to most recent release fixed the search issue.